# plotting fixed effects from lme4

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, sjplot, lmertest

I am plotting the estimates from the fixed effects model. Is there a way to only plot some of the fixed effects, rather than all?

```
sjp.lmer (model.name,
      type = "ri.pc",
      facet.grid = FALSE)
```

I am also using lmerTest to obtain p values for reporting. Is there a way to add p values to a plot to demonstrate which fixed effects reach signficance?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sjPlot::plot_model()` and select terms with the `terms` argument or remove terms with `rm.terms`. see `?plot_model` for more details.